# Pushing filenames to array and then writing them into a text file

Tags: node.js, arrays, for-loop, foreach, fs

Okay so I have a little nodejs FTP uploader I made that uploads files that I have stored in a directory locally and transfers them to my webserver.

After the files are uploaded I am trying to make it append information in a `recent.txt` file that includes the web url and files uploaded to that url.

However I am having trouble trying to `.push();` the filename into the `dirFiles` array.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const ftp = require("basic-ftp")
const open = require('open')
const path = require('path');
var ncp = require("copy-paste");


//random string for url gen function
function rand(length) {
    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
            charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}


//the actual upload
async function Upload() {
    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
        await client.access({
            host:
            user: 
            password: 
            port: 
        })
        client.trackProgress(info => {
            console.log("File", info.name)
            console.log("Type", info.type)
            console.log("Transferred", info.bytes)
            console.log("Transferred Overall", info.bytesOverall)
        })


        client.trackProgress(info => console.log(info.bytesOverall))

        //needed variables for shit
        var rand_string = rand(5); //can change this from rand to a previous upload folder
        var share_url = `https://molex.cloud/${rand_string}`;
        let uploadDir = `/HOSTED_WEBSITES/molexCloud/.sh/${rand_string}/`;
        const localDir = '_upload_these/';
        const recent = "recent.txt"


        await client.ensureDir(uploadDir)
        await client.uploadFromDir(localDir, uploadDir)
        client.trackProgress()

        //copy share url to clipboard
        ncp.copy(share_url, function() {
            open(share_url);
        })


        // formatting for the recent.txt
        let date_ob = new Date();
        let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);
        let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
        let hours = date_ob.getHours();
        let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();
        //Array to store filenames
        var dirFiles = [];
        //scan local dir to add filenames to dirFiles array
        fs.readdirSync(localDir, function(err, files) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            //push to array in foreach
            files.forEach(function(file) {
                dirFiles.push(file);
                console.log(`PUSHING: ${file}`);
            });
        });
        //seperators, date, and time
        var _u = `__________________________________________________________`;
        var _d = `..........................................................`;
        var _t = `On ${month}-${date}-${year} at ${hours}:${minutes}`;


        //format to store url in recent.txt
        var linkFormat = `${_u}\n\n  ${share_url}\n${_d}\n  ${dirFiles}\n${_d}\n  ${_t}\n${_u}\n>\n`;
        // EXAMPLE:
        //  __________________________________________________________
        //
        //    https://molex.cloud/aB123
        //  ..........................................................
        //    test.txt
        //    test.png
        //  ..........................................................
        //    On MM-DD-YYYY at HH:MM
        //  __________________________________________________________
        //  >
        //

        try {
            //check if recent.txt exists
            if (fs.existsSync(recent)) {
                //append recent.txt
                fs.appendFileSync(recent, linkFormat);
                console.log('\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m', `Adding url to list .............. ${share_url}`);
            } else {
                //create and append
                fs.writeFileSync(recent, linkFormat, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    //recent.txt created and file written successfully
                    console.log('\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m', `Creating recent upload list ..... ${recent}`);
                    console.log('\x1b[33m%s\x1b[0m', `Adding url to list .............. ${recent}`);
                })
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    //console info
    console.log('\n');
    console.log(`\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m`, `Opening default web browser...`);
    console.log('\n');
    console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'Link copied to clipboard...');
    console.log('\n');
    console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', `Shareable Link:`);
    console.log(`\x1b[30m\x1b[42m\x1b[4m%s\x1b[0m`, `${share_url}`);
    console.log('\n');
    console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', `Type \x1b[35m'links'\x1b[32m in the terminal for a list of recent uploads.\x1b[0m`);

    client.close();
}



Upload();
```

Here is a screenshot of how it currently display (no filenames)
[image: Screenshot of how file list is empty]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm still learning this whole async, awaits, syncs, and scopes. I was still trying to use a callback function on a synchronous FS method.

```js
//scan local dir to add filenames to dirFiles array
var files = fs.readdirSync(localDir);

//push to array in foreach
files.forEach(function(file) {
    dirFiles.push(file);
    console.log(`PUSHING: ${file}`);
});

// create a string with all of the dirFiles elements, split by newline
var fileString = dirFiles.join('\n');
```